# How to add multiple pages to a print preview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm making a program that takes screenshots of multiple forms and stores them into bitmaps. The problem comes when I want to preview these bitmaps for printing. I want to have these forms displayed in a single printdialogue that has several pages in it. Here's my current code that is not working

```
    private void ButtonFinalPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Image img in bmplist)
        {
            index++;
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
            pd.Print();
        }
    }

    private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = bmplist[index];
        Point loc = new Point(100, 100);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);
    }
```

I have bmplist as an instance variable. thank you so much, guy!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop.

```
private void ButtonFinalPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  index = 0;
  PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
  pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
  pd.Print();
}
```

Use the HasMorePages property to determine if the routine gets called again:

```
private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = bmplist[index];
    Point loc = new Point(100, 100);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);
    index++;
    e.HasMorePages = index < bmpList.Count;
}
```